# Asp.Net MVC 3 prevent duplicate records

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, exception, crud

I'm new in Asp.net MVC 3 with Entity Framework.

I followed a tutorial to make a simple program that add/edit and delete records from a SQL database.

My question is how and where I must prevent the duplicate records? I have the "firstName" field as unique. So, when the user add a record from the form, how I can control that this record don't exist?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have an unique column then it'll be generated an exception when you try to insert a new record.

Comment: Yes, how I can control that exception?

Comment: If you don't want to catch the exception (!) best way is to query for a record with the same FirstName (using FirstOrDefault() to get only the first one or better Count()) and do not even try to insert the record.

Comment: Adriano, thanks for your answers. I think my error is not know about the catch exceptions. Is that the best way to control the duplicate records?

Comment: No, it's not the best way because - usually - exceptions should be used to manage...exceptional situations and a duplicate entry is a common situation (especially if is the user to enter data). I suggest to always catch exceptions on insert (in case something bad happens) but check for this with a query (so you can give the user a good and meaningful message).

Comment: Ok then I need to add code to control the add() method in controller? Sorry but I'm very new here.

Comment: @Adriano FirstOrDefault() doesn't means that it is a unique value.

Comment: @plurby If you search for an entry with the same unique value and extract only first entry then you can say if it's unique or not.

Comment: You're missing the point of my comment. SingleOrDefault() guarantees that the value is unique as it does top(2) query.

Answer (score 0):

You can write something like following to catch known issues with the incoming data and only end up with an exception where the data suffers from an uncommon problem:

```
public class PersonController
{
    public ActionResult Add(PersonModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid /* && check whether model represents valid data */)
        {
            try
            {
                // create Person record here (this logic might throw exception)

                return View("AddSuccess");
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                return View("AddError", exception);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelErrors("", "description of model error found");
        }

        return View();
    }
}
```

There are better ways of structuring this code, using slightly more advanced design patterns but this should be a start.

In general, you want to avoid getting an exception thrown because usually it is slower than checking for erroneous input.

Comment: No need to put TryCatch blocks in the controllers. There should be "skinny". Just override the SaveChanges() and log all the exceptions in one place.

Comment: The try-catch there allows the controller to display a different view, in this case. Controllers should be skinny, but there is no need to make them one-liners, either.

Comment: Using EF you can log exceptions in one place,as i have stated. And depending of the result display the message or redirect. Why repeat TryCatch in every controller when you don't need to.

Comment: @plurby, what you are suggesting is a bad idea in my opinion, because it mixes up web logic in the repository. The data access layer should neither know, nor care about what is happening elsewhere. The approach you are suggesting is bad design because it introduces coupling between data access and UI layers.

Comment: How does it introduces coupling. You override SaveChanges() in the data layer and it logs all data related exceptions. There is no web logic in the repository.

Comment: plurby, there's 2 issues here, logging the exceptions that occur and reacting to those exceptions in a meaningful way. Sure, you can log the exception in the overridden SaveChanges method, but you also need to react in a meaningful way to the exception and you cannot do that if the error handling is within SaveChanges. Also, what if the exception is not being thrown by SaveChanges but by something else? You really need to review your fetish for overriding SaveChanges.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(ModelState.IsValid)
{
    if(db.A.Any(ac=>ac.Name.Equals(a.Name)))   
    {
          return;
    }
    else
    {
        db.A.Add(a);
        db.SaveChange();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial completely explains to avoid duplicate records insertion in asp.net mvc , here in this tutorial we have used jquery validaton plugin to restrict duplicate username Read more http://www.dotnetqueries.com/Article/137/prevent-duplicate-values-using-jquery-validation

[image]

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score -2):

Here's a quick example:

//here you mark the entity as added

```
Context.Entry(yourPersonEntity).State = System.Data.EntityState.Added;
```

//and here you return true or false is the insert succeeded

```
bool isSaved = Context.SaveChanges() > 0;
```

and depending if the isSaved is true or false you do what you want.

Logging exceptions is preferable but i recommend that you do it by overriding `SaveChanges()` of your context.

Also don't use `FirsOrDefault()` as it just returns a first value, and not guarantees that the value is unique.

> Returns the first element of a sequence, or a default value if no
>   element is found.

Use `SingleOrDefault()` as it preforms top(2) query, and if there is more than one result it throws an exception.

> Returns the only element of a sequence, or a default value if the
>   sequence is empty; this method throws an exception if there is more
>   than one element in the sequence.

Comment: `FirstOrDefault() != null` works like `Count() > 0` or `Any()`; because they're applied to a **query** it's implicit that you search for an entry with the same (unique) value (anyway I wrote it in the comment...). To use exceptions for this is always a bad idea (so old discussion, right?). The biggest drawback of query is that it needs an extra round to DB but you can show to the user a meaningful message about the existing record.

Comment: That's what i wanted, a detailed explanation so that @Fabian understands the implications and benefits.

Comment: :) well if I wasn't lazy to write I did write an answer instead of comments!!! LOL Anyway he has to catch exceptions too because of concurrent requests. I think to check before insert instead of just catch exceptions makes sense every time you can give a good feedback to the user ("Sorry, you can't insert a patient with ID 123 because that ID is assigned to someone with another name (XYZ). Check ID you entered or verify ID for XYZ is correct bla bla bla" instead of "Sorry, cannot insert new record because of an error")

Comment: Agree and +1 on the comment. I have a message response system similar to Gmail notifications for my MVC apps. I didn't said he doesn't need to log exceptions, rather that it is better approach to log them in one place and with EF that is possible and easy to do. And for the down voters, you are hurting the community.

Comment: actually I agree with both you and Umar, in general I would log the exception (or the fact) in a centralized way but I would reroute the user to a proper page (re-edit, review, merge or error) too.

Comment: In the context of an ASP.NET MVC application, my approach would be to use a filter, rather than muck around overriding the DataContext's SaveChanges method. That is just plain wrong, even if it is possible. Logging exceptions is useful but without some kind of overall context, that logged information would be pretty useless in a large application. Context is important to discern patterns which can then be utilized to fix the exceptions.

Comment: How will it be useless?!. I use this approach in enterprise applications where the detail is greater that using Triggers or StoreProcs for auditing changes. It's logging the previous state of entity, the changed state and if there's an error the error is logged in the separated table, stored as JSON so i can examine it. Similar to StackExchange.Exceptional for real time monitoring requests. For the exception not related to DB and entities i use trycatch where needed, but mostly a framework that handles exceptions.

Comment: I think everybody has made their point. There is nothing more to be gained by reiterating our respective points of view.